# ssh-add Has No Effect

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, ssh-agent, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to add password-less ssh access to my Mac OS X 10.8.3 that acts as a server. I've followed instructions like this:

http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/25/how-to-set-up-a-password-less-ssh-login/

But when I do ssh user@myserver.com I still get prompted the password.

After looking at:

https://superuser.com/questions/419122/how-to-use-ssh-private-key-to-log-in-without-entering-passphrase-every-time-on-m

When I do ssh-add on my client machine I get:

```
[michael@varga (Sun May 26 09:56:32) ~]% ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /Users/michael/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

BUT when I tried using the ssh-add command at the command-lin on the server and it simply does nothing:

```
[michael@maz (Sun May 26 10:00:25) ~]% ssh-add
[michael@maz (Sun May 26 10:01:03) ~]% ssh-add -K
```

I think this may have something to do with the issue I'm having with it still requiring me to give the password.

Any suggestions how to fix ssh-add?

Comment: Have you already started and sourced `ssh-agent`?

Comment: Consider using [`keychain`](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain) as a `ssh-agent` wrapper

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to run `ssh-add` or `ssh-agent` on your server.

You should run `ssh-agent` on your client (`varga`). This will create a socket for `ssh` program to check for an unlocked key. `ssh-agent` will print you some environment variables you'll have to define—you normally do this with `eval $(ssh-agent)`, which both starts the agent and exports all necessary variables.

As I can see from your question, `ssh-add` asks for a password and adds the key to the agent, that means that the agent is running and all those variables are exported (at least in the shell you are using to run `ssh-add`). But now to make `ssh` see the agent you have to make sure that those variables are also exported in the session in which you run `ssh`.

The fact that `ssh-add` is not asking for the password when you run it on the server means that the agent is running on the server (you don't need it) and there are simply no keys to add, so it quits silently.

Why is `ssh` on the client asking for the password? Probably because you've added a wrong key to the agent. Are you sure that you can log in to the server *using the key-file*? Are you sure that when you try to login it is asking for the password *of the key-file*, and not a normal user password? Ensure that pulbic-key authentication is working first.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing one of two things.

Either you haven't got an ssh-agent running on the server. TO verify that you have an ssh-agent running on the server, see if the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable is set:

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Another possibility is that you have misunderstood how ssh keypairs are supposed to work. Have you installed your public key on the server? If you have ssh-copy-id available, this is very simple. On the client:

```
ssh-copy-id user@server
```

If not, you need to insert the contents of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub on the client to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server. E.g. (assuming you have no other keys set on the server):

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server:.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh user@server chmod 0600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

A way to diagnose this is to run ssh with verbose output:

```
ssh -v user@host
```

It should show you that keypairs can be used for authentication:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

That it actually tries to authenticate using a key:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/$user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And that the public key authentication succeeds:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: True enough. How do you like the improved answer?

Comment: Much better! :)

Comment: There is no reason to run `ssh-agent` on the server.  `ssh-agent` should run on the client only.  If you want multi-hop capability, configure `ForwardAgent yes`, then the server will have access to the client's SSH agent.

Comment: @200_success I try not to presume what he is trying to do, but yes, usually running ssh-agent on the server is the wrong thing to do.